# Django HttpResponse didnot return any object?

Tags: django, httpresponse

I am doing a project in django that runs a matlab file which allows me to upload image when pressing a button in html page, and shows me the result which is another image also.

The button pressed and run the file and shows me the image i want. But after it is uploded, it shows me the result, the images disappear immediatly, and the page shows me error :

```
ValueError at /myviews/

 the view apps.homepage.views.myviews didn't return an HttpResponse object
```

the code in views in python is like this :

```
def myviews(request):
    session = MatlabSession()
    session.run('path to matlab file')
```

so, it's asking me to mention an HttpRespone object to be returned at the end of this view, but i dont want the page to go anywere, i want it to show me the images only.

Comment: You need to return a `HttpResponse` object at the end of every view - that's how Django knows what to display on a given page. Maybe start by reading [the official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/) to learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you my friend, i know that. but i am asking if any way to avoid this. I want just calling that file in matlab and show me the image without going anywhere.

Comment: Returning an HTTP response doesn't constitute "going anywhere". Every HTTP request needs a corresponding HTTP response. That's a basic fact about the protocol and not a Django issue. If you want to do something "in the background" without changing the page shown in the browser you can make an AJAX request using JavaScript.

Comment: thank you so much. i am sorry if i didnot make my question clear. i will try to make it clear. The job of matlab file that i want to run from python by pressing a button in html is asking me to upload image and detect it if it is forged, that mean it will detect it and show me another image with the forged parts (it is a method named ' A robust detection algorithm for copy move forgery in digital images'). after it shows me the result (as image), the image goes and the page asks me for an HttpResponse object. is there any way to make the result (image) stay or saved ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call the view and you don't really care about the answer, simply do:

```
return HttpResponse('')
```

Each django view **must** return a HttpResponse object. This object doesn't necessarily need to be text/html, you can also return an image with it if you want - but if I understand your question correctly, then the above return statement should be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. i will explain again. The job of matlab file that i want to run from python by pressing a button in html is asking me to upload image and detect it if it is forged, that mean it will detect it and show me another image with the forged parts (it is a method named ' A robust detection algorithm for copy move forgery in digital images'). after it shows me the result (as image), the image goes and the page asks me for an HttpResponse object.

Comment: I'm not sure how do you upload your image and display one later - i don't know if the page is reloading or not, or you're doing it using javascript. What I know, however, is that you most certainly have to do two things: display a page and handle the post request - which is also a page that has to be returned by the user. Both **must** return a `HttpResponse` object, it doesn't matter if it's empty or not. Your `apps.homepage.views.myviews` view doesn't do that - it' probably returning some other object, or not returning anything at all (in the last case it returns None).

Comment: thanks. I upload the image and matlab detects it and displys the result in anothe image. check this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YseIWJDBR3w . I did a similar code and run it using python. in the video it shows the result. but using python view by pressing a button, i must give an HttpResponse. I want any way to save that result image in python or html. thank you again my friend

Comment: You generate a http request, and you will require a http response. This is the language that django will actually understand. Each view accepts a HttpRequest object, that is created out of the real http request, and must return a HttpResponse object, that will be converted back to a RFC-valid http response.

The problem isn't really about how do you handle the image from the user perspective. The problem that you stated in your first post is on the other side.

Comment: If you want to only display an image, you can return a HttpResponse with binary image data and image/jpeg mime type. Or you can render a html page and display it there. The first method could be useful if you want to have a ajax-based user experience without any reloading. Both ways will work however. And both ways will require you to return a HttpResponse object.

Comment: Tank you so much. May you please give me an idea how i can save the image that the matlab displays, and then i read it using html. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you mean by 'matlab displays'. I don't know matlab at all, I can only help you from python/django perspective.

Comment: Ok my friend. How can i upload an image to my page using django.

thank you so much for helping